# Chrome Browser Doesn't supported image orientation property

Tags: angular, css

I am trying to use image orientation property in my application but it's doesn't support in chrome browser. What could we use to do so ?

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer but personally I wouldn't bother trying to get it to work. The image-orientation property is barely implemented by [any](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-orientation) browser except Firefox. And even Firefox states it will most likely be [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation).

Comment: @Mathyn I have tried but it's supported in the mozilla browser only, can you please provide us the solution in angular 5 or angular 6, angular7

Comment: Please edit your question so a code sample demonstrating your problem is included. This way we can take a look at your code and see if there is a solution available.

Comment: Chrome browser doesn't support "image Orientation CSS property" is there any solution to this issue

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can try to use the [blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) library.
You can see a demo of this product working [here](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/).
 Hope it helps !

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can use [johansatge/jpeg-autorotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-autorotate) NPM package for Angular.

Comment: Can you please provide me the solution in angular

Comment: Please provide us a solution in angular

Comment: @SwathiMarreddy I edited my post with an Angular solution.

Comment: I have checked code, but it was developed in angularjs

Comment: @SwathiMarreddy I edited my answer. However, you should tag your question with the additional technologies next time. It would be quicker to give you the proper answer. :)

Comment: I have checked with this code ( johansatge/jpeg-autorotate ) but it's not working, let me know is there any solution

Comment: @SwathiMarreddy You asked to know what you can use in place of 'image orientation property', not to fix a piece of your code. I believe I answered your question. If you need some assistance in order to fix a not working piece of code, ask for it while providing the related code.

Comment: @SwathiMarreddy relax! No need to spam asking for a solution. We all got other things to do than monitor this website all the time...

Comment: @Skrface, please provide us the better solution for this issue

Comment: Waiting for your reply

Comment: Your question is about what you could use rather than image orientation property. I did answer to that question. To mark it as answered would be great for start. If you are still facing troubles while trying to code something, please ask a proper question providing the code you tried and the issues you are facing. SO is not a free coding service, it is 'only' a kind and helpful community.

Comment: Image orientation CSS property doesn't support in angular code, as you have given an explanation is not useful for us, so kindly help with us